# Redesign Request: ASK QUESTION Rollover / Hover State

Tags: feature-request, bug, design

The button for "ASK QUESTION" while appears to be working is incredibly subtle in my opinion. Not really a bug but if it could be a bit more obvious like when you rollover the tags I think it would be a lot better.

Even the "Questions Tags Users Badges Unanswered" is extremely subtle (on Meta, these are fine on the regular site). Maybe just making the grey lighter? Or change to the Red or something.

Comment: Agreed. All of the hover states could stand to be more distinct, on both sites.

Comment: Oooh "Hover" thats the word I should've used. Knew something was off in my phrasing.

Comment: Sometimes there's a word right on the tip of the tongue, isn't there? Been there! :)

Comment: maybe a solid fill is the way to go

Comment: Here here - I love the tag button hover animations and was surprised that the Ask Question button wasn't the same. Personally I'd give all the outlined buttons a matching hexagonal style and matching hover animation - I like the angular thing and think it could be used more as a distinctive theme. I might try green diamonds instead of green circles for the question list page too, but maybe that's just me.